# How to clear Windows Phone Developer Registration 8.1 app account cache

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to register my device with Windows Phone Developer Registration 8.1, but it's taking the account that I previously used for registring another device, for current device I need to register with new account, so how can I clear previous account cache? Tried restarting the App, Phone but still it's taking old account.